# does the final EXE file of scapy need another dependent file

Tags: python, tcp, py2exe, scapy

i want to code a program using `scapy`, e.g. send a custom packet using scapy, and after finishing the program, i want to convert the python file into EXE file using `py2exe`, in order to use on windows platform without `python` . but i noticed that the installation of scapy for windows needs a lot of dependent file, such as `pywin32`, `winpcap`, `pypcap`, `libdnet`, `pyreadline`, after conversion to  exe file using py2exe, should the user install multiple file to make the program executable? my program intends to be executed in various computers. i dont want users to install so many dependent file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to accomplish what you want.  Even for the simplest scripts Py2Exe will require many dependent files.

As for Scapy it will definitely need winpcap. I would assume it needs most of the others as well.  You could probably get away without readline, but at that point why bother?